# How to tell my boss that I need a trackpoint on my laptop

Tags: hardware

I am starting to work in a new company. I am getting hired as senior software engineer. They asked me, what hardware I 'request'. As always, I answered: Gimme something with a **[trackpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointing_stick)** and able to run an up-to-date Linux. Preferably a Thinkpad.

They ordered and sent and a Dell XPS **without trackpoint**. I assume someone just forgot to check (was the case last time) for the trackpoint to exist, before ordering.

This happens not the first time. But I need a trackpoint in my daily work life. As an Apple user, I would get the UI I am used to, but as a trackpoint user, I feel that I get constantly ignored with my demands. (I never got en_US keyboard layout from any company here in Germany, even if I always ask. This request just gets dropped silently all the time. The effect is not so drastic as the missing trackpoint though)

Yes, I can and will use an external keyboard, but in essence this ruins the benefits of a mobile computer. Also, I feel lowkey forced to change a very personal behavioral choice. This is comparable of being forced to write with the left hand, even if one prefers the right one naturally.

To me, It is totally unclear, why I get asked for hardware requirements at all, If they are getting ignored in the end.

My question: Should I escalate this and insist to get the UI I am used to or should I just quietly accept the fact that they don't really care and continue to look for another job? Or should I offer byod? Or do you have other options in mind? How could I get what I need to work without being seen as 'special' or overly picky?

**Update**

The company did send an external lenovo keyboard with en_US layout. So I am under the impression that my request was understood correctly. I described the usage of the trackpoint as **extensive** in my request.
I also specified some laptops that would work for me. I am aware that lenovo is currently the last brand that offers trackpoints.

Comment: You said you are a new joiner to this company: do you have any reason to believe they are purposefully denying your choice? Can you just talk to the IT department (or whoever is in charge of providing the laptops) to remind them about the actual request? Some _may_ have thought of the trackpad as a trivial item.

Comment: Have you contacted IT, the Boss, HR ? Or did you just post here first?

Comment: @SouravGhosh You mean, I should escalate and try to get the laptop changed. Considered this, but are unsure.

Comment: @SolarMike I first posted here. I had hardware that does not work for me a few times now. This time I am not willing to accept this at all. I want to get a broader view before deciding anything. As I statet, I see that I could escalate and try to get the laptop changed. But I don't see this working. I tried this a few times now in different companies.

Comment: Your first job in Germany? You are not supposed to be working on a laptop keyboard an the small screen full-time, anyway.

Comment: If you are so dependent upon this specific input device, you should be asking about it in the interview to ensure that the prospective employer will provide you with the hardware you demand.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler No, I am actually a native. I do work with external keyboards a lot, but that is not an option in a meeting, train or mobile home office.

Comment: @alroc When I do that, I get promised a lot and delivered nothing. The hiring staff has no clue about the IT supply policies. They promise everything, but cannot guarantee it in the end. I had this a few times now. Last time the guy ordering sat in front of me in a 2 person office and was absolutely aware about my requirement. He ordered new fancy laptops without trackpoint anyway. That's why I am so frustrated. The requirement 'trackpoint' seems to be widely disesteemed. (See some comments suggesting to just learn to use a trackpad here)

Comment: @ansi_lumen before signing is the right time to ask.   Not "Can I get a laptop with a trackpoint" (as you noted the people you're talking to probably don't know if IT procurement policy can be given an exception even if they know what you're asking for) but "What brand laptops do you use?" If the answer is anything other than "Lenovo" or "Your Choice" (possible at some smaller companies); you can rule them out.  If they say Lenovo, you can drill down into more specifics since IIRC only some Lenovo models have the nub.

Comment: Why do you need a trackpad? It's likely IT considered it a minor preference rather than a requirement. Do you have a disability that requires it? Is it going to make you significantly more productive?

Answer (score 8):

> They asked me, what hardware I 'request'. As always, I answered: Gimme something with a trackpoint and able to run an up-to-date Linux. Preferably a Thinkpad.

The ways in which this kind of "request" is fulfilled can vary quite a bit from company to company.

- Some places only ask to appear accommodating but will simply give you whatever they want to give you.
- Some places will ask for input and then try to meet you halfway by finding the "next closest thing" from a short list of pre-approved options.
- Some places will give you a short list of pre-approved options and honor your request for whatever selection you make from that pool.
- Some places are just expecting a specific make/model request so that they can simply rubber-stamp a purchase order.

Seeing as they gave you a Dell XPS without a trackpoint, you don't really know what sort of situation you are currently in.  Your *"Gimme something with a trackpoint and able to run an up-to-date Linux. Preferably a Thinkpad."* comment might have sounded so easygoing and flexible that they thought you'd be perfectly content on the Dell.  It would be dumb to think that it was done *purely* to spite your request; more likely it is one of those "we already bought something like this for the last guy and he's super happy" kind of scenario, or "this is the closest thing on our secret pre-approved list" kind of scenario.

The big question now is how do you react?  Probably the least confrontational way to address the issue would be to send an email to your manager (or whoever was in charge of requisitioning you the device), and saying something along the lines of *"I just received my company laptop but I think there might have been a shipping error as this make/model doesn't have the trackpoint I had requested."*  That should be minimally confrontational whilst giving you some way to learn more info about what kind of requisition paradigm your new company operates under.  Either they will try to work with you in some way to find a better alternative, or they won't.  But both scenarios give you more information to decide if you want to grin and bear it, put your foot down, or offer a byod compromise.

---

> I assume someone just forgot to check (was the case last time) for the trackpoint to exist, before ordering... This happens not the first time... To me, It is totally unclear, why I get asked for hardware requirements at all, If they are getting ignored in the end.

As this seems to be a recurring issue for you, you may need to try altering your current approach moving forward to see if it helps.

Firstly, if "no-trackpoint" is practically a deal-breaker to you, then that strong preference should be clearly indicated so that the person in requisitions can weight that factor more appropriately.  Trying to sound nonchalant and non-picky by saying something like *"Anything that'll run Linux is fine, and I suppose a trackpoint would be nice."* makes it seem that you have a passing preference for trackpoints like one might prefer a light-grey over a dark-grey exterior.

Secondly, what nomenclature(s) are you typically using? In written form *"I need a laptop with a trackpoint."* looks extremely similar to *"I need a laptop with a trackpad."* and is likely to be read as such (especially considering the relative minority marketshare of trackpoint devices).  Writing out something like *"I need a laptop with a nub/nubmouse/trackpoint."* is much more difficult to be mistakingly glossed over as *"... trackpad."*

Lastly, the presentation may matter as well.  A bullet-pointed spec list is likely much better than a couple sentences.

> In order of importance:
>
> - Nub/nubmouse/track**point** for "mouse" input (Dealbreaker?)
> - Comfortably run latest Linux release (maybe some target sub-specs for CPU,RAM,etc. here)
> - SSD Drive for OS
> - U.S. keyboard layout (low-priority)
> - Blue/Black color (very low-priority)
>
> e.g. "Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 9 Laptop", "Lenovo ThinkPad P1 Gen 4 Mobile Workstation"

Something like the above might be more useful.  Yes it might come off as "more picky" than you'd like to appear... but it's better to get things right the first time rather than risk drawing MORE attention to yourself for progressively-pickier reorders after-the-fact.  And, lastly, offering a few examples of acceptable models that can just be copy/paste searched might just mean that *they* pick from *your* list because it's just easier than hunting down and comparing specs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your opinion. I realize that trackpoint and trackpad can be mistaken. Fun fact: I got an external lenovo keyboard from the company. So they pretty much understood, what I requested. But the laptop itself seems to be from a 'hidden list of approved devices'. Also, I specifically hinted some laptop models that would work for me and also described the usage of the trackpoint as 'extensive'.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following: Most laptops do not have a trackpoint (I had to actually look up on google what a trackpoint is, it is **not** the same as a trackpad).  In fact, the only laptops I've ever worked with that have trackpoint are IBM Thinkpad laptops; every other laptop I've ever used or owned did not.

From the employer's side, when the employer provides equipment, they do not special-order each laptop for each employee special.  The IT department has an office somewhere where they have stacks and stacks of laptops, and when a new hire joins the company, they take a laptop off the stack, format it, and present it to them.  That's how it works (source: I've worked for such a department before).  If you request a specific hardware requirement that they don't have on their standard-issue hardware and is not able to come by as an external attachment, then you're simply not going to get what you want; the company isn't going to custom order a brand new laptop that does not conform to their specs just because a random junior new hire asked nicely.  Among many other reasons why they won't do this is because the IT department is trained on how to use certain machines, so if your special custom one breaks down, it's going to be a massive headache for IT (again, I've done this before so I have some context).

Simply put, your request for a trackpoint was not a reasonable one.  Their standard-issue hardware does not support it, and I don't believe there are external attachments that do support it (and you mentioned in the comments that you would not be amenable to such a solution anyway if it existed).  They did their best, which is to provide you with a functional laptop with which to do your work, which did not have the trackpoint.  You can take it, or you can leave it (and leave the company as well).  If you know of an accessory which has the trackpoint you desire, you can raise that to your manager and ask the manager if you can buy one of those and expense the cost to the company; many companies will be amenable to this as a solution if it will help your productivity.  This is the best option you have.

As a side note, it is inadvisable to work on a trackpoint.  It is not ergonomic to work on a laptop in the first place, as the screen is often too small, too bright, and too close to your face, and it promotes bad, hunched-over posture.  Furthermore, the angle your wrist is placed to use the trackpoint is not a good angle for wrist health and you will find that you develop muscular issues with prolonged use.  Trackpads are also bad for many of the same reasons, and it's advisable, if you can, to work on a desk, with a full-sized keyboard and mouse, wherever/whenever possible.  Trackpads/trackpoints should only be used for short durations when other accessories are not accessible; if the issue of having or not having a trackpoint is critical for you, chances are you may have larger issues at hand that need to be dealt with.

Comment: Trackpoints were a thing in the 90s, already.

Comment: Just one comment on ergonomics: I used a left handed mouse for decades.  A few years ago I developed a shoulder injury that became pretty severe.  It has become apparent that this was directly due to using a mouse.  I experimented with a keyboard with a trackpad but settled on a right handed trackball.  So I wouldn't necessarily say that a mouse is "more ergonomic" than other pointing solutions.

Comment: The ordering process for equipment depends on the size of the company. My unit has ~20 employees, we need 1-2 new notebooks every year. We order each of them separately based on what the employee and the boss agree on.

Answer (score 1):

The question you asked is "How to tell my boss that I need a trackpoint on my laptop". The straightforward answer is next time you speak to your boss (assuming that's fairly regularly as you are new in the team, if not you'll have to try to set up a meeting/catch them in the corridor/phone/IM/email as appropriate to your office/remote setup and team communication culture) you say "hey {boss} I asked for a trackpoint on my laptop. I perhaps didn't make it as clear to IT as I should have that this was a need rather than a preference, for {specific reason} and the machine supplied doesn't have one. Would you support me going back to IT and asking for a swap?"

Nobody here can be sure what the response will be. It will depend on your employer's IT policy and whether your boss/company IT assesses your need really to be a need or a preference. If it's a medical requirement, they should be accommodating but where I work that's about the only reason they would consider to deviate from the menu of about 4 standard specification Dell machines, and they might look for a medical opinion. Perhaps you have a less bureaucratic employer and they'll swap your machine for a different machine from the menu which has a trackpoint, or even order you a fresh one a la carte, or perhaps you'll get told you have to stick with what you've got until it needs replacing, in which case you choose whether to insist it's a genuine (medical?) need that they have to meet (if the answer is still no, are you prepared to put a case to HR that your need for this input device is such that it's discriminatory if they don't meet it?) or ask about BYOD policy.

From the comments, you seem resistant to suggestions that you should do what you've asked in the question how to do, based on having got negative responses from previous employers. But until you do that, you can't know what the answer is at the current place, and so can't know what you need to do to follow up. This isn't chess - you only need to know 1 move ahead.

TL;DR If this is genuinely something you'd consider quitting over, as you suggest, you need to ask a fairly simple question in a nonconfrontational way, be prepared to justify "need" over "want"/"prefer" and take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

> My question: Should I escalate this and insist to get the UI I am used
> to or should I just quietly accept the fact that they don't really
> care and continue to look for another job? Or should I offer byod? Or
> do you have other options in mind? How could I get what I need to work
> without being seen as 'special' or overly picky?

If a trackpoint is a real *need*, then you should express that need to your company, and work together to find a way to fulfill that need. Explain to them why you *need* one and  why their normal input devices won't suffice.

If on the other hand, it's just a *preference*, then you should indicate that it's something you prefer and ask if there is a way to get one.

Unless you are willing to leave your job over this issue, you aren't in a position to insist.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is a requirement and yes I am willing to quit - as stated - if this gets ignored.